# In how many ways the $8$ people $A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H$ can be arranged around a square table assuming two people $A$ should not be seated in front of $B$.

Tags: combinatorics, factorial

In how many ways the $8$ people $A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H$ can be arranged around a square table assuming  $A$ should not be seated in front of $B$.

Also

$\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$ [image]

The rightmost one is the same as the middle one, however they two are different from the leftmost one.

---

The number of arrangements that $8$ people can sit around such a table is $2\cdot7!$
On the other hand for each one of the sides one of the two cases happens:

[image]

The number of such arrangements is $2\cdot6!$, so the desired answer is  $2\cdot7!- 2\cdot6!=12\cdot6!=8640$

But the answer is $5760$

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is correct. Look at it this way:

- First, seat $A$ in $8$ possible ways
- Then, seat $B$ in $6$ possible ways ($B$ not directly in front of $A$)
- Finally, seat the remaining people in $6!$ possible ways

Accounting for the four rotations of the table, we find:

$$\frac{8 \cdot 6 \cdot 6!}{4} = 8640$$

Comment: @45465 I found the 5th edition, which mentions that $A$ and $B$ cannot be seated next to one another. Here, the answer is $\frac{8 \cdot 5 \cdot 6!}{4} = 7200$ (verified solution [here](https://www.slader.com/textbook/9780201726343-discrete-and-combinatorial-mathematics-an-applied-introduction-5th-edition/14/exercises/36/)). Looking back at it, $5760$ would be the number of ways in which $A$ and $B$ are not seated next to each other or in front of each other.